# React-Quill behaving in weird manner

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

React-Quill toolbar not displaying correctly.

[image: Displaying in this weird way]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to it.

if you are using react.js you need to add the following line in your index.js.
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.6/quill.snow.css">`